# Why is a truncate - insert query not rolled back?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, truncate

I'm truncating the table and then insert new data. Somehow we got error like (size more in data).  It gives error but truncate statement is not rolled back.

Could you please suggest what is issue and how to roll it back?

```
try {

    utx.begin();
    List<Company> company = CompanyMapper.MAPPER.entityListToDaoList(query);
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"Truncating Table Company!!");
    emTarget.createNativeQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE Company").executeUpdate();
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"Table Companyrole Company!!");
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"Populating Table Company!!  - " + company.size());
    for (Company row : company) {
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"ROW:" + row.getCompanyid() 
        + "| Address:" + row.getVisitaddress1() 
        + "| Size:" + (row.getVisitaddress1()!=null? row.getVisitaddress1().length():"0"));
        
        emTarget.persist(row);
        
        
    }
    logger.log(Level.INFO,"Populated Table Company!!");
    utx.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        utx.rollback();
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Persist transaction failed. Rollback activated", e.getMessage());
        throw new PersistenceException("There was an error reading the source table");
}
```

I'm using Oracle.

Comment: Which db are you using?

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the Oracle documentation of [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNCATE-TABLE.html#GUID-B76E5846-75B5-4876-98EC-439E15E4D8A4), you cannot roll back:

> **Note:** You cannot roll back a `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement, nor can you use a `FLASHBACK TABLE` statement to retrieve the contents of a
> table that has been truncated.

If you want the ability to roll back, you will need to use [`DELETE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DELETE.html#GUID-156845A5-B626-412B-9F95-8869B988ABD7) instead (this may be a lot slower than truncate).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `DELETE` instead of `TRUNCATE`

`TRUNCATE` is DDL while `DELETE` is DML.

There are several database implementations where DDL cant be rollbacked.

Comment: So you mean first load whole data into objects and for loop to all deletes?

Comment: No. You can run delete all command. In HQL `DELETE FROM enityName`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot roll back TRUNCATE. But if you have to - use DELETE instead.